# How to fetch specific array into object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

hello I'm trying to fetch data from specific URL but the URL contains tow keys as below

```
{"users":[],"warnings":[]}
```

I want to target the users array and  I'm using this approach

```
    async function getData(){
const apiUrl = "https://MyURL"
const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
const mydata= await response.json()


const firstname= mydata.data.map((x) => x.users.firstname)
console.log(firstname);
}

getData()
```

The console returns me Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.
So how to target the specific key?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: What is `mydata`? The JS seems to think it doesn’t have a data property, or that it’s value is undefined

Comment: First of all please show your `API Raw Response`.

Comment: when I console log mydata it returns me both users and waring arrays with their data. so I want to to return users array

Comment: But you’re trying to map over data? Why not try mapping over users?

Comment: Then you seem to have made up a property `data` and need the `mydata.users` array. Try `const firstname= mydata.users.map((x) => x.firstname)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.json()` returns response.data parsed as JSON. Your response is already in `mydata`, so `mydata.data` is undefined. You can access the users list with `mydata.users` directly.
Additionally, your response data is an object (`{"users":[{"firstname": ""}],"warnings":[]}`) which does not contain the method `map` which is for arrays. You can use `map` on `mydata.users`, which is the array of users in your response

```js
async function getData () {
  const apiUrl = "https://MyURL"
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
  const mydata = await response.json()

  const firstNames = mydata.users.map(user => user.firstname)
  console.log(firstNames);
}

getData()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you receive your data in the format:

```js
{
  "users":[ 
      {firstname: 'firstname1'}, 
      {firstname: 'firstname2'}
    ],
   "warnings":[]
}
```

```js
async function getData() {
  const apiUrl = "https://MyURL";
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  const mydata = await response.json();

  const firstNames = mydata.users.map((x) => x.firstname).filter(Boolean);
  console.log(firstname);
}

getData();
```

This would log all the `firstnames`, in this case:

```js
['firstname1', 'firstname2']
```

The `filter(Boolean)` is to not include falsy values.
The `response.json()` do not return a data object, but the direct values.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use users instead of data in map function and second mistake is that you are using x.users.firstname, use x.firstname instead.

```js
    async function getData(){
const apiUrl = "https://MyURL"
const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
const mydata= await response.json()

const firstname= mydata.users.map((x) => x.firstname)
console.log(firstname);
}

getData();
```